# Apollo Mock Error state -> Error: No more mocked responses for the query

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, react-testing-library

**What am I trying to do?**

Using `MockProvider` from `@apollo/client/testing` to mock out error state of a query.

**What do I expect to get?**

The component uses `useLazyQuery` to query something from backend, and returns an `error`, which will trigger the component to render the error message.

The component is working as expected.

**What actually do I get?**

> Error: Uncaught [Error: No more mocked responses for the query ... And the test does not pass.

**What have I tried?**

1. Final state is working as expected. I tried removing the error state in the mock data, everything worked as normal.
2. I tried to wait longer, and it does not help
3. I tried to log the error in the component, I could see the error. It looks like the MockProvider is missing something, and it errors out before even rendering the component
4. I tried to remove the `data` portion, or added it back into the mock. See code below

**Where are your codes?**

Try #1

```
const mock = {
      request: { query: GET_REFERRER_FROM_CODE, variables: { input: "edx" } },
      result: {
        errors: [new GraphQLError("Error!")],
        data: {
          userGetReferrerFromCode: {
            id: "abc",
            firstName: "Leo",
            lastName: "Qiu",
          },
        },
      },
    };
```

Try #2

```
const mock = {
      request: { query: GET_REFERRER_FROM_CODE, variables: { input: "edx" } },
      result: {
        errors: [new GraphQLError("Error!")],
      },
    };
```

Basecode

```
<MockedProvider addTypename={false} mocks={mocks}>
   ...
</MockedProvider>
```

Comment: Did you find solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

From experience, I've found that the error field does not need to be nested in the result to trigger an error.

e.g.

```
const mocks = [
    {
        request: { query: GET_REFERRER_FROM_CODE, variables: { input: "edx" } },      
        error: {
            message: "Something went wrong",
        },
    }
];
```

Then when using

```
const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(GET_REFERRER_FROM_CODE, {
    variables: { input: "edx" },
});
```

`error` will contain the object from the mock.

Answer (score 1):

If your code does multiple requests (or refetch) you need to duplicate your mock x times.

So if you do `query1`, then `refetch query1`, you need to provide 2 exact same mocks eg `[mock1, mock1]`